# Add namespaces to XML from XSD

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, xsd

For example I have XML:

```
<a>
 <b>c</b>
</a>
```

xsdA.xsd:

```
<xs:import schemaLocation="xsdB.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="a" xmlns:xsa="http://www.example.org/a" type="xsa:aType"></xs:element>
```

xsdB.xsd:

```
<xs:element name="b" xmlns:xsb="http://www.example.org/b" type="xsb:bType"></xs:element>
```

I want to somehow transform XML into this:

```
<xsa:a xmlns:xsa="http://www.example.org/a">
 <xsb:b xmlns:xsb="http://www.example.org/b">c</xsb:b>
</xsa:a>
```

I hear that it can be done by JAXB, but is there any way to do this without code generation?
I use Java.

EDIT:

It's just example. I can add namespaces by xslt or manualy in DOM object, but my xsds is 170K size now. And it often changes. I want just replace the xsd and program keep working.

How can i found namespace of element with given localname in bunch of xsd files?

EDIT2:

All localnames seems to be different in my xsds.

Comment: Yes, you could use JAXB, but if this transformation is all you want to do, something like XSLT might be a superior choice.

Comment: I have very big xsd and can't write so much templates. I edit my question.

Comment: You can use XSLT to locate an element with a certain local name in an XSD file (one or more) and then use this to transform the XML. - Is there one top level XSD which (recursively) imports all the others? - Why is it necessary to add those namespaces? Isn't it possible to generate the XML correctly?

Comment: Yes, i have one top level xsd which import all others. How to locate namespace of element in xsd by xslt? XML comes from another system and can't be with namespaces because of backward compatibility.

Comment: Problem is that although the namespace definitions are in the XSDs there is no simple way of associating a name from an element definition with the namespace to which it belongs. Can you provide and maintain a text such as `xsdA http://www.example.org/a`, `xsdB http://www.example.org/b`? Perhaps as a simple XML one can read in the transformation and use for finding the namespace URI?

Answer (score 2):

As laune suggested, a very basic XSLT that should get you started.

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
                xmlns:xsa="http://www.example.org/a" 
                xmlns:xsb="http://www.example.org/b">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="a">
        <xsa:a><xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" /></xsa:a>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b">
        <xsb:b><xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" /></xsb:b>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input:**

```
<a>
  <b>c</b>
</a>
```

**Output:**

```
<xsa:a xmlns:xsa="http://www.example.org/a" xmlns:xsb="http://www.example.org/b">
   <xsb:b>c</xsb:b>
</xsa:a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but i have very big xsd and can't write so much templates. I edit my question.